# Как правильно позиционировать элементы в css

Tags: html, css

вот простой код с картинкой, как сделать эту картинку таким образом:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.main_picture{
     size: 10%;
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
     }
```

```html
    <p class='main_picture'>
<img src="https://wikiway.com/upload/hl-photo/5e6/40f/most-adolfa_17.jpg" alt='pic.png'>
    </p>
```

Comment: Что такое `size: 10%;` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.main_picture{
     height: 30%;
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
     margin: 0 20px;
     overflow: hidden;
     }
     
 div{
 height: 100vh;
 position: relative;
 }
 h1{
 text-align: center
 }
 .main_picture img{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
 }
```

```html
<div>
<p class='main_picture'><img src="https://wikiway.com/upload/hl-photo/5e6/40f/most-adolfa_17.jpg" alt='pic.png'></p>

 <h1>Тут ваш сайт</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: а можно как нибудь сжать картинку, а не обрезать?

Comment: конечно, поправил пример